# Load content using attributes data

Tags: jquery

I have a portfolio: when I click on an image, a modal window appears and shows a header and a bigger image. The header text is stored in 'data-title-type'. I think I can get the bigger img url from the href attribute, but I don't know how. Would you please help me? Thanks!

```
<div class="container"> 
    <h2 id="titpl"></h2>
</div>  

<div onclick="showInfo(this)" data-title-type="Work title" href="img/bigimg.img">
    <img src="img/img.jpg"/>
</div>

function showInfo(title) {
    var imgtitle = title.getAttribute("data-title-type");
    var imgref = title.getAttribute("href");
    document.getElementById('titpl').innerHTML = imgtitle
    <!-- what now? -->

}
```

Comment: I solved it using this: document.getElementById('imgsp').src = imgref;

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this: document.getElementById('imgsp').src = imgref;